# Why is one of the monsters in Where the Wild Things Are smaller than all the rest?

Tags: where-the-wild-things-are

When Max first crosses the sea in Maurice Sendak's *[Where the Wild Things Are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Wild_Things_Are)* (1963), he is greeted by a number of creatures, including one that stands out from the others, by being much smaller.

[image: Max arrives in the land of wild things.]

This same creature (white with half-moon horns) appears again on the next page.

[image: Max frightens the wild things.]

However, Max subsequently interacts with a set of wild things that are all of uniform height.

[image: King of the wild things]

So why was this one monster different?

It looks like, if Sendak was drawing the illustrations page by page, he might not have standardized the appearance of the wild things at this point.  The shorter wild thing is also mounted on another beast that initially appears to be a quadruped; however, that same wild thing appears again later, in a clearly bipedal posture (seen below, for example).

[image: Wild rumpus]

But given that Sendak gave many interviews talking about *Where the Wild Things Are*, did he ever explain the size discrepancy?

Comment: According to the makers of the WTWTA film, each of the monsters represent BIG emotions whereas the "goat boy" (now named Alex) represents a small emotion, personal insecurity. I'm not sure how closely that's supposed to align to the original work though. You might also want to note that at the start of the original book/s, our hero encounters a huge sea monster, many times larger than the other "wild things".

Comment: That's a good point. Now that I think about it I wonder why more monsters _weren't_ smaller because those could be considered scarier. I'd rather have a big monster which is easier to see and, possibly, to avoid than a tiny one. Maybe that's what Sendak was thinking about... a bigger monster might be less scary and more lovable.